# Unity - Turning off ambient light is not making my scene completely black

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been looking around for a way to make my scene 100% dark, except for the single light source, and all of my sources mention turning off ambient lighting which I have done.

As you can see, light still permeates my scene.
[image: As you can see, light still permeates my scene.]

It appears that only the X axis has been darkened where the Y and Z are still lit by a light source that I don't have. The only light source is the single orange source at the center of my scene. This is extremely frustrating because all help sites say to turn off ambient lighting which I have done, I have not found any other solutions.

Comment: Might have something to do with the "Directional Light" in your scene(Second object in the hierchy...).  Just a guess.

Comment: That was exactly the issue and I am just a stupid who forgot that was there thank you and sorry for dumb question

Answer (score 0):

I had a directional light that I had forgotten about, rookie mistake